# GitLab auto devops: Dockerfile build-args

Tags: docker, gitlab, gitlab-ci

I'm new to GitLab auto-devops feature and I intend to build the project using my own Dockerfile available in the project root.

The problem is, my build is a bit complex and uses multiple build arguments. But, none of the documentation (or the resources I came across) explain how the auto devops would deal with build arguments -- in other words, how I should feed auto-build job with the necessary build arguments to build my docker image.

https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/topics/autodevops/index.html#custom-buildpacks

Or do I've to customise the auto devops .gitlab-ci.yml template to build the image using custom Dockerfile with build arguments?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the variable `AUTO_DEVOPS_BUILD_IMAGE_EXTRA_ARGS` in your job with, for example,`--build-arg=YOUR_ARG=YOUR_VALUE` as value

More info here: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/topics/autodevops/#passing-arguments-to-docker-build